# App crashing on heroku with :dependent => :destroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, crash, dependent-destroy

Note everything works in local enviromnment

This is the code

```
PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity.class_eval do

attr_accessible :reference_type, :reference_id

has_many :notifications, :dependent => :destroy_all
has_many :users, :through => :notifications



end
```

This is with the public_activity gem

the error is

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_many.rb:20:in `configure_dependency': The :dependent option expects either :destroy, :delete_all, :nullify or :restrict (:destroy_all) (ArgumentError)
```

if it expects `:destroy_all` and I wrote `:destroy_all` and it works locally.. then what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_many.rb#L20)!

```
unless options[:dependent].in?([:destroy, :delete_all, :nullify, :restrict])
  raise ArgumentError, "The :dependent option expects either :destroy, :delete_all, " \
                       ":nullify or :restrict (#{options[:dependent].inspect})"
end
```

So in that error message, the part that says `(:destroy_all)` is just telling you what you provided; the list of what it was expecting is before that.  You probably want `:destroy` instead. Can't say why it worked locally and not on Heroku; might be some sort of gem version problem.

Comment: would :destroy work as intended (delete all notifications in association with the delete model)?

Comment: I think `:destroy` would work as intended, per the docs for `has_many` here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many. Also, the link you provide is for the `destroy_all` method on an ActiveRecord `Relation`. So you can call it in code to destroy all, but can't provide that as an option to the `has_many` method in your model definition.